# Node result is not getting printed as per the documentation

Tags: java, netbeans

I am following the tutorial mentioned over [here](http://www.vias.org/javacourse/chap14_02.html) and trying to print the result in the node as mentioned in the doc by the statement `System.out.println (node);`. I have done almost sam thing in Netbeans IDE. Here is my code from NetBeans:

```
public class Node {


           public class NodeClass{
                int fele;
                Node next;

                public  NodeClass(){

                    fele = 1;
                    next = null;
                }


                public  NodeClass(int fele , Node next){

                    this.fele = fele;
                    this.next = next;
                }

                public String toString(){
                    return fele + "";
                }
           }


          NodeClass node = new NodeClass(1,null);
          System.out.println( node);





}
```

Here is the image for the same :

[image]

Could anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have instructions directly in the class body. You must put those lines in a main method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    NodeClass node = new NodeClass(1,null);
    System.out.println( node);
}
```

Why the inner class though? Try this:

```
public class Node {
    int fele;
    Node next;

    public Node() {
        fele = 1;
        next = null;
    }

    public Node(int fele, Node next) {
        this.fele = fele;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return fele + "";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node node = new Node(1, null);
        System.out.println(node);
    }
}
```